# need to take the earliest date of each month

Tags: f#

I have a dataset with dates shown below. I need to take the earliest date from each month for all years. How would I go about doing this?

```
[(1/2/2004 12:00:00 AM);(1/5/2004 12:00:00 AM);
 (1/6/2004 12:00:00 AM);(1/7/2004 12:00:00 AM);
 (1/8/2004 12:00:00 AM);(1/9/2004 12:00:00 AM);
 (1/12/2004 12:00:00 AM);(1/13/2004 12:00:00 AM);
 (1/14/2004 12:00:00 AM);(1/15/2004 12:00:00 AM);
 (1/16/2004 12:00:00 AM);(1/19/2004 12:00:00 AM);
 (1/20/2004 12:00:00 AM);(1/21/2004 12:00:00 AM);
 (1/22/2004 12:00:00 AM);(1/23/2004 12:00:00 AM);
 (1/26/2004 12:00:00 AM);(1/27/2004 12:00:00 AM);
 (1/28/2004 12:00:00 AM);(1/29/2004 12:00:00 AM);
 (1/30/2004 12:00:00 AM);(2/2/2004 12:00:00 AM)]
```

Dataset continues on. Too large to paste here.

EDITED:

```
let data =
    Datacsv.GetSample().Rows
    |> Seq.map (fun ((yr,mon),(name,price))
```

For `(name,price)` on the last row, I get the error:

```
TermStructure.fsx(33,36): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'CsvProvider<...>.Row'    
but here has type
    ''a * 'b'
```

Comment: are they in string format or proper date time format?

Comment: DateTime format

Comment: I'd use `groupBy` to group them by month (AND year, since you don't want Feb. 2004 to combine with Feb. 2005). Then sort each group and take `List.head` (or `Seq.head`) of each group. I don't have time right now to turn this into a proper answer, but if you're struggling with how to do that then I'll be happy to explain in more depth later on, when I have more time.

Comment: @rmunn I understand everything about that except how you would iterate through each tuple and take the head of each group

Comment: You wouldn't iterate through a tuple, you'd iterate through one part of the tuple. I.e., you'd pass each tuple into a function `fun ((month, year), dataList) -> ((month, year), List.head dataList)`.

Comment: Thanks. I encountered an error and have updated the question accordingly. These small errors baffle me. @rmunn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. But your last line, with `(name, price)`, isn't quite right. When you call `Seq.head data`, what is `data` at that point? Answer: a list of rows. So `Seq.head` will give you one CSV row. You can't match a CSV row to a `(name, price)` tuple, and that's what the error message is telling you. Since the input is a row, it was expecting a function that takes `((yr, mon), row)` and you gave it `((yr, mon), (name, price))`.

In your case, I'd probably back up a step and instead of just doing `Seq.head data` and feeding that into another `Seq.map`, I'd do it in one operation. I'll show you my suggestions one step at a time. First, here's the code that you wrote, which is getting the error:

```
let data =
    Datacsv.GetSample().Rows
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun row -> row.DATE.Year,row.DATE.Month)
    |> Seq.map (fun ((yr,mon),data) -> ((yr, mon), Seq.head data))
    |> Seq.map (fun ((yr,mon),(name,price))
```

My first thought is that having two different things named `data` in your code is going to be confusing. So let's change the variable name in the first `Seq.map`. The thing you've named `data` in that function is a sequence of rows, so let's call it `rows` instead:

```
let data =
    Datacsv.GetSample().Rows
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun row -> row.DATE.Year,row.DATE.Month)
    |> Seq.map (fun ((yr,mon),rows) -> ((yr, mon), Seq.head rows))
    |> Seq.map (fun ((yr,mon),(name,price))
```

Now we'll fix the second `Seq.map` by removing it and merging its operation into the first `Seq.map`, as follows:

```
let data =
    Datacsv.GetSample().Rows
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun row -> row.DATE.Year,row.DATE.Month)
    |> Seq.map (fun ((yr,mon),rows) ->
        let row = Seq.head rows
        ((yr, mon), (row.NAME, row.PRICE)))
```

Note that I'm assuming that since your CSV file has a column called `DATE` in all caps (which has translated to a `DATE` property on your row objects in F#), it also contains `NAME` and `PRICE` columns in all caps too. If those columns are named something else, adjust the `row.NAME` and `row.PRICE` parts of the code accordingly.